# Get the real max of an array in D3

Tags: jquery, arrays, max, d3.js

I am using jQuery to bring in a string of comma-delimited numbers for plotting purposes in D3.  I'm trying to get the max of this array but it is not going well.

```
var x_data = $('.CostImport').text().split(',');
var y_data = $('.PriceImport').text().split(',');
var r_data = $('.SalesImport').text().split(',');
var c_data = $('.ZoneImport').text().split(',');


 for (i = 0; i < x_data.length; i++) {
   data.push({ "x": x_data[i], "y": y_data[i], "c": c_data[i], "r": r_data[i] });
   }

alert(d3.max(r_data));
alert(d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.r }));
```

Both of these alert pass me the same number, which is incorrect.  The actual max is 928870 but I am getting back 9975.  Plotting everything works fine (scatter plot, with r determining size and c color), so I'm a bit flummoxed why I can't pull the maximum number.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the values are being treated as strings. You will need to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` (depending on the precision of the values) to convert them to integers for the `max` function to work as you are expecting.

Here's a quick function to convert a string array to int. This would be better prototyped, but for a quick and dirty example this will work:

```
function toIntArray(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        arr[i] = +arr[i]; 
    } 
    return arr;
}
```

Keep your code as is, but amend these lines:

```
r_data = toIntArray(r_data);
data = toIntArray(data);

alert(d3.max(r_data));
alert(d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.r }));
```

Comment: So I changed my original code to 
alert(d3.max(data, function (d) { return parseInt(d.r) })); 
and it worked.  What's odd is that when I was graphing it before, I had a scale and used d3.max(r_data) for the max value.  The item with 9975 did indeed set the radius max, meaning the items with 1000000+ took up the whole screen.  So d3 recognizes these as numbers in plotting, but not when looking for the max.

Comment: Glad to hear it. The `toIntArray` function should help you if you need to use sorting or comparison functions on the other arrays too.

Comment: I would imagine that d3 has some internal validation which converts the values to ints for the plotting, but not in max.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this same problem, but I was dealing with a data object instead of array. Found the filter function in d3 quite useful when converting strings to digits. Below is an example

```
data.filter(function(d,i) {
    d.x = +d.x;
d.y = +d.y;
});

xmax = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.x });
console.log(xmax);
```